# remove content inside parenthesis as well as the parenthesis themselves from a paragraph

Tags: python

I need to remove the parenthesis and content within each set of parenthesis from some text.

I would like to do this with regular expressions. However, I don't know the first thing about re in Python.

text   Direxion, a leader in alternative investment solutions, has named Angelo Pirri as its new Senior   Regional Director for the Northwest Region. (Logo: http://photos.prnewswire.com/prnh/20100701/NY29766LOGO) Mr. Pirri is responsible for selling and distributing all of Direxion's buy-and-hold alternative investment strategy products to financial advisors across all channels, including wirehouses, regional broker dealers, registered investment advisor (RIA) and others in his territory. Mr. Pirri will serve advisors in northern California, Oregon, Washington, Hawaii, Wyoming, Idaho, Alaska, and Montana....

get rid of the stuff in parenthesis...

I haven't tried anything yet... I want someone else to tell me what to do, I don't want to do any work.

Comment: yeargh... buddy it would look something like this  text (text) text

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: i guess this is not so easy, let's assume that there are no sub sets of parenthesis with in the parenthesis... we need to look for the closing bracket... i'm wondering if someone has already built such a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = "Some sample (with parenthesis) text"
regEx = re.compile(r'([^\(]*)\([^\)]*\) *(.*)')
m = regEx.match(text)
while m:
  text = m.group(1) + m.group(2)
  m = regEx.match(text)
print text
```

It's just a matter of formatting the right regex to match your text... The above will iteratively remove sets of parenthesis from a string, one set at a time, but fail if you have nested parenthesis. That's a whole different problem.

Comment: THANK YOU!   I'm going to assume there aren't any nested parenthesis as that would be a potentially difficult complication to deal with , and I don't think it will occur very much

Comment: actually this is the one I'm putting in my script. thanks!

Comment: The other solution is better.. :) Or at least cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming no nested parentheses:

```
import re

string = 'text (text) text (text) text'

regex = re.compile('\(.+?\)')
output = regex.sub('', string)

print(output)
# >>> text  text  text
```

Comment: thanks, can you tell me whether this solution is preferable or not to the other one? I would like to use whatever is better if they are not equivalent

Comment: this is working for me i'm going to use it in my script,  WOOHOO stackoverflow is AWESOME